# Decimal / Float in mongoose for node.js

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I start my first test app on node.js / mongoDB / mongoose, this is a very simple app that aims to crate record in DB and retrieve them.

I create a model like:

```
var Car = new Schema({
    brand : String,
    speed  : Number,
    date  :  { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

This is working fine, except that I would like to be able to provide a float value for speed instead of the integer one. I gave a try to Decimal and Float but none of them are working.
I did not find in the documentation either.

Any idea ?

Comment: `var car = new Car({brand: "", speed: 0.5});`

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I've searched a bit and [found this article stating that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/f437FCPsVLY) for storing float values you must use `Number` type. You can store any float value in `speed` field.

Comment: thanks a lot . But, in this article, it seems it's more the other way round, ie to force a float into an integer, right ? Sorry, I maybe misanderstood the thing.

Comment: @Luc: Exactly, in article about forcing float into an integer. But it's mean that you can store float value in field with type `Number`. So `Number` type should be used for both types: integer and float.

Comment: @Bugain13, thanks a lot, you'r right. There is something strange I should have done because it was not working at first place. Thanks a lot for your help !!!!

Comment: You should be warned: When using number and aggregations like summations with Mongoose you will get Ulps problems. (insertion of a 1 after dozens of Zeros behind the point)

Comment: it just convert float to int. and nothing else

Comment: But, we can not store the value like 1.0 or 1.00 like this this value converted into Int

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can use the `Decimal128` type.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-Decimal128

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **Decimal128** in Mongoose Schema as

```
speed:{
type:mongoose.Types.Decimal128
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can create your custom one. like so

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

class DoubleType extends Number {
  constructor(v) {
    super(v);
    this.value = v;
    this._bsontype = 'Double';
  }

  toBSON() {
    return this;
  }
}

class Double extends mongoose.SchemaType {
  constructor(key, options) {
    super(key, options, 'Double');

    Object.assign(this.$conditionalHandlers, {
      '$lt': val => this.castForQuery(val),
      '$lte': val => this.castForQuery(val),
      '$gt': val => this.castForQuery(val),
      '$gte': val => this.castForQuery(val),
    });
  }

  cast(val) {
    if (val == null) {
      return val;
    }
    if (val._bsontype === 'Double') {
      return new DoubleType(val.value);
    }

    const _val = Number(val);
    if (isNaN(_val)) {
      throw new mongoose.SchemaType.CastError('Double',
        val + ' is not a valid double');
    }
    return new DoubleType(_val);
  }
}

mongoose.Schema.Types.Double = Double;
mongoose.Types.Double = DoubleType;

module.exports = Double;
```

***source is copied from @mongoosejs/double***

Comment: Como faria o uso?

Comment: @EzequielTavares waa

Answer (score -4):

While the mongoDB fully supports float type, the mongoose supports only type of Number which is integer. If you try to save to mongoDB float number using mongooses type of Number it will be converted to string.

To sort this out, you will need to load some plugin for mongoose which will extend its value types. There are some plugins which work best with currencies or dates, but in your case I would use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-double.

Your model after changes would look something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('mongoose-double')(mongoose);

var SchemaTypes = mongoose.Schema.Types;
var Car = new Schema({
    brand: { 
        type: String 
    },
    speed: {
        type: SchemaTypes.Double
    },
    date: {
        type: Date, 
        default: Date.now 
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: I have just found that in 2018, the mongoose added support for `Decimal128` so you can simply just use `mongoose.Types.Decimal128` for your schema

Comment: No it won't. You can store numbers like 25.50 as a number and it won't be stored as a string