# nodejs and mongodb: how model a geolocation?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm developing an API to store locations, including their coordinates, but I have no idea to model those.
Should i go with

```
latitude: { 
 type: Float 
},
longitude: {
 type: Float 
},
```

or is there a way of modeling them as an array, like [43.95 ,  -26.75]?
I want later to filter them distance.

Comment: I found some docs about it. Maybe that would help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

Comment: mongodb is weak schema-ed, you can think it is kinda json store, for coordinates, you can either store them as an object: {lat: xxx, lng: xxx} or you can store them as array [lat, lng].

Comment: It's really a matter of opinion. But if you intend to query the database for "nearest" etc, then I would suggest storing in a [supported format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-data), and probably best as GeoJSON.

Answer (score 4):

recently I worked on geo-location things, I think I can answer your question, its too late but may be this help others who is looking for solution.

```
location: {
  type: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Point',
  },
  coordinates: [Number], // [22.2475, 14.2547]  [longitude, latitude]
};
```

in above manner we have to introduce this attribute in our schema definition. Then  we need to create a **2dsphere** index in our collection like below: -

```
db.collection.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )
```

that's it, now you are open to fire a query, based on location

```
db.collection.aggregate([
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [22.4568, 14.5412],        
            },
            key: 'location',
            distanceField: 'distance', // in meter
            spherical: true,
          },
        }
        ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [MongoDB's Geospatial Data](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#geospatial-data)

> In MongoDB, you can store geospatial data as GeoJSON objects or as legacy coordinate pairs.

Then you can use [Geospatial Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/#id1).

Comment: How should I model my schema?

Answer (score 1):

Best is to store them as GeoJSOn data , Then it is easy to query by apping a 2dsphere index.

One example of this type of storage is :-

```
"geolocation" : {
         "type":"Point",
         "coords":[-71.1410879999999960,42.4051060000000040]      
    }
```

The schema format :-

```
geolocation: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [Number],
}
```

Comment: so, my LocationModel.js should be like:
'locationName: {
    type: String,
    Required: 'Enter the name of the location.'
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    Required: 'Enter the description of the location.'
  },
"geolocation" : {
         type: String,
         coords:[float,float]      
    }'

?

Comment: I have GeoJSOn installed but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: this way i can input the coords like 45.33, however GeoJSOn uses like 45,33 (meaning lat 45 and longi 33). Maybe Number, Number?

Comment: I cant submit 2 numbers this way at all.

Comment: For storing floating numbers you must use Number type . Please refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605551/decimal-float-in-mongoose-for-node-js

Comment: Would you like to interest in  giving values manually without schema?Like when you enter (12.9716,77.5946) gives you the key values like { lat: 12.971600079908967, lon: 77.5946000777185 }

Comment: That answer didnt help at all. I need to submit 2 numbers, but i always get a  "Cast to Array failed for value" error when I try to. How should submit these 2 numbers from a web application?